# How to make column labels on R barplot italic

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

This is probably a simple question, but how do I make just the column labels on a barchart italic, not the `x-axis` label, but the column labels specifically.
The code I have so far is

```
bp = barplot(means, names.arg = c("CON", "TRI"), ylim=c(0,120), ylab="PA", xlab="M")
```

Comment: the `names.arg` you mean? `barplot(1:2, names = expression(italic(CON), italic(TRI)))`

Answer (score 6):

Here's one solution that is also easy to adapt for the case when you know the names ahead of time (e.g., `names2use <- c("CON", "TRI")` and you want to use that object to specify the names):

```
barplot(1:3, names.arg=c("one","two","three"), font=3, yaxt="n")
axis(2)
```

Comment: huh, I didnt realize font could be passed like that without affecting the other text, this is better/easier than the comment