# Making axis labels italic when using names.arg (R)

Tags: r, italics

I have labelled my axis using the function names.arg, just wondering how to make these labels italic. Here's my code below. (Using R)

```
barplot(species_and_abundance_$Abundance, ylim = c(0,44), names.arg = species_and_abundance_$Species, las=2, cex.names = 0.8, ylab="Species Abundance", xlab="Species")
```

Comment: Have you tried `font = 3` in `barplot` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907689/how-to-make-column-labels-on-r-barplot-italic

Comment: Hi, yes that works thanks! Is there a way to apply it just to those labels rather than the y axis as well?